# Where to put username & password that remote machine needs to allow files access from desktop application

Tags: c#

Check this illustration please
http://www.fa6er.com/Image1.png

Where to put username and password that the desktop application needs to access files in shared directory on a server within local network by IP?

```
string var_main_dir = @"\\192.168.1.244\c$\repository";
```

After this line the application make a connection to the server -BUT- stop and shows debug error message regarding

and invalid username and password

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

Additional information: username and password

Answer (score 1):

Before connecting to the server you will need to impersonate the login using the username and password you have. The following stack overflow should help a bit with writing that code: [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net).

A shortened version is:

```
    public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        var ok = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
                       LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 0, out this._handle);
        if (!ok)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser returned error code {0}.", errorCode));
        }

        this._context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }
```

Good luck!

Comment: There is also [that tiny little impersonator helper class](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) I've once wrote.

Comment: @Uwe Kiem, How to use your class.Do have I create new class? and paste it there?